# Navigating content without changing the "View"

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, view, navigation

I started with flex for mobile a few months ago, and I find it very interesting. I am now building a mobile app, but I don't know how to go further.

I have a TabbedViewNavigatorApplication, with 3 ViewNavigators. In one of these ViewNavigator, I want to change the content, but not the whole view (e.g. I don't want the actionbar to slide). Please have a look at the attached image. How to do this? Please support me as soon as possible.

http://s18.postimage.org/8k9km920p/adobe_companion.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Where is the content coming from? It looks like you are using a List to display the contents. When you set the dataProvider to different content it will update the content.

Comment: the content is static.I have it in a text file which will be embedded into the app.I can save the data in XML format or what so ever.So do you mean to make like this?Inside my view:  protected function b1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
   arr1=new ArrayCollection();
   arr1.addItem({name:'Peter'});
   list.dataProvider=arr1;}  
  protected function b2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
   arr2=new ArrayCollection();
   arr2.addItem({name:'Jasson'});
   list.dataProvider=arr2;}